# Hide Title Bar of Dialog in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I was using this dialog as message pop up and i want to hide the title bar
Is there any way to hide title bar of Dialog?

```
   import QtQuick 2.7
   import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

   Dialog {
       standardButtons: DialogButtonBox.Ok

       property alias text : textContainer.text

       Text {
           id: textContainer

           anchors.fill: parent

           horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignLeft
           verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignTop
           }
       }
```

Comment: You're not setting a title though?

Comment: Can't reproduce with Qt 5.9.1. If you don't set the Title property nor the Header property, as in your example, there is no title bar.

Comment: Are you sure, you are not using `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`?

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `Popup { }` instead of `Dialog { }`  to get a modeless popup box.

See documentation on Popup

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html

Also change the  second line to `QtQuick.Controls 2.3`